# gtkentry is editable but not work, can't write!

Tags: quickly

I'm followed steps this tutorial http://developer.ubuntu.com/get-started/

But my 'quickly' have problem when create a `gtkentry`. I can't write any letter, not have focus and when press tab button, not have focus too.

I created a new ubuntu-application but not work `gktentry` too. I don't understand this problem.

Comment: nobody saw my question?

Answer (score 3):

The `GTK_CAN_FOCUS` flag is required to be set.

If using Glade to develop the UI, you can click on your `GtkEntry` element, then in the Properties panel, click on the Common tab, then toggle the **Can focus:** button to `Yes`.

Run your application again and you will be able to set focus to the field and enter text.

Comment: It works but very strange that such a common and generic widget needs a custom settings every time added to the window.

Answer (score 0):

Even if you have set your `GtkEntry` widget with `can-focus` set to true, you might still not be able to focus on it if it is a child of another widget that has `can-focus` set to false.

In my project, I had to go up to all the ancestor nodes and change their `can-focus` properties in the Glade XML file. Then finally the `can-focus` property was respected on my `GtkEntry` widget.